# Topological Condition ensuring that the Diagonal is measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, compactness, borel-sets, separable-spaces

I try to figure out under which conditions the Graph of a continuous surjection $\pi:X\to Y$ (think quotient map) between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is measurable
with respect to the product-$\sigma$-algebra.

I could reduce it to the measurability of the diagonal
$$ \Delta_Y = \{ (y,y) | y \in Y\} $$
with respect to $B \otimes B$.
Where $B$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

So my question is:
Under which topological condition is the diagonal measurable in the product of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra.
In particular I want to know conditions on compact Hausdorff spaces.

The situation is clear for metrizable compact spaces
as then the product of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of the product (and the diagonal is closed by Hausdorffness).
I would like to see any condition that is weaker than second countability (i.e. metrizability).
Or is this in fact equivalent to metrizability?

I already found in a paper of Hoffmann-Jørgensen ("Existence of Conditional Probability Measures", Theorem 3)
that the measurability of the diagonal is equivalent to the existence of a countably generated sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ which contains the points.
This is in turn equivalent to the existence of an measurable injection $f:Y \to [0,1]$.

So yet again I can reframe my question to:
What topological properties ensure the existence of a Borel-measurable injection to the compact interval?

Again this is clearly true for Polish spaces but I hope for a non-metrizable class of spaces with that property.

Thank you all!